# Need Help Regarding Product Display

Tags: website-design, interface, user-centered-design, user-attention

I need help regarding product display **on the product page**. There are many websites offering different price for same product (just like Amazon, Flipkart, Shopclues etc.)

How can I show **multiple buttons** below product to show multiple deals to the user? There will be pop-up including specification table on hover the each button. Is there **any effective way** to show this?

[image: Product UI and table]

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered offering the users just the best offer and then letting them decide if they'd like to see the rest?

Amazon is doing this by giving you the lowest price on a product, then providing a link to other offers giving the users the freedom to choose if they need to.

[image: Yellow highlight indicates the other offers available]

This would have the added effect of not [overloading the user with options](https://uxplanet.org/design-principles-hicks-law-quick-decision-making-3dcc1b1a0632) and streamlining their selection process.

Comment: This is too old style. Company wants to stick to the current method. Tell me if this can be aesthetically good looking and user friendly.

Comment: I agree the style Amazon uses might be a bit dated. But the concept remains the same. Not overloading the user with options whilst giving them the ability to choose is overall better for the UX and your conversion rates.


How you want to utilise it UI-wise and make it fit your app's layout is up to you.


Now, if you **have** to stick to your current design I would suggest against pop ups, especially for a mobile view.



Instead have the offers laid out as you do, with each having a dropdown button/arrow and the specifications table expanding when the user selects the dropdown.